How to use Camel Caffeine
I was using caffeine cache earlier in a spring project(not springboot). The way I used it was by declaring LoadingCache and use it wherever required as shown below
LoadingCache<String, DataObject> myCache = Caffeine.newBuilder().build(key -> loaderFunc(key));

And performed operations such as
//putting data into cache
myCache.putAll(myMap)

//retrieving data from cache
resultMap = myCache.asMap()

Now inorder to make this myCache globally(in other services) through uri, I am using camel-caffeine. But I am not able understand the existing documentation of camel-caffeine.
I have following questions about using the camel-caffeine.
1.How should I modify my current usage( declaration, putting data into cache and retrieving as shown in code snippets above) to use camel-caffeine in a similar manner.
2.How to configure the camel-caffeine in such a way that I can access it from a uri?
Thanks
